# Why does a SIGTRAP PTRACE_EVENT_STOP occur when the tracee receives SIGCONT?

Tags: c, linux, ptrace

I'm using `PTRACE_SEIZE` to trace the execution of a child process, but I'm running into an issue where a non-group-stop `PTRACE_EVENT_STOP` (signal == `SIGTRAP`) is being emitted when the tracee receives a `SIGCONT`. I can't seem to find any documentation that might indicate why this is happening. From what I can gather in the `ptrace(2)` manpage, `PTRACE_EVENT_STOP` only occurs when one of the following conditions are true:

- The tracer called `ptrace(PTRACE_INTERRUPT, ...)`
- The tracee entered group stop (signal is `SIGSTOP`, `SIGTSTP`, `SIGTTIN`, or `SIGTTOU`)
- The tracee called `fork`/`vfork`/`clone` and the tracer automatically attached to the new process/thread

In the sample program below, I'm getting a `PTRACE_EVENT_STOP` with signal `SIGTRAP`, but it doesn't match any of those 3 conditions. When I run the program, I get the following output:

```
[Child] Raising SIGSTOP
Event for pid 29236: Tracee entered group-stop PTRACE_EVENT_STOP (signal: 19)
Event for pid 29236: Tracee entered non-group-stop PTRACE_EVENT_STOP (signal: 5)
Event for pid 29236: Tracee entered/exited syscall
Event for pid 29236: Tracee entered/exited syscall
Event for pid 29236: Tracee received signal (signal: 18)
Event for pid 29236: Tracee entered/exited syscall
[Child] Resumed from SIGSTOP
Event for pid 29236: Tracee entered/exited syscall
Event for pid 29236: Tracee entered/exited syscall
Event for pid 29236: Process exited
```

Any ideas as to what this particular `PTRACE_EVENT_STOP` means?

---

Sample program:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void handle_events(pid_t pid_spec)
{
    while (1) {
        int status;
        pid_t pid = waitpid(pid_spec, &status, __WALL);

        printf("Event for pid %d: ", pid);

        if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
            printf("Process exited\n");
            break;
        } else if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
            printf("Process killed by signal\n");
            break;
        } else if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
            int ptrace_event = status >> 16;
            int signal = WSTOPSIG(status);

            switch (ptrace_event) {
                case PTRACE_EVENT_STOP:
                    if (signal == SIGSTOP || signal == SIGTSTP
                            || signal == SIGTTIN || signal == SIGTTOU) {
                        printf("Tracee entered group-stop PTRACE_EVENT_STOP (signal: %d)\n", signal);
                        ptrace(PTRACE_LISTEN, pid, NULL, NULL);
                    } else {
                        printf("Tracee entered non-group-stop PTRACE_EVENT_STOP (signal: %d)\n", signal);
                        ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, pid, NULL, 0);
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    if (signal == (SIGTRAP | 0x80)) {
                        printf("Tracee entered/exited syscall\n");
                        ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, pid, NULL, 0);
                    } else {
                        printf("Tracee received signal (signal: %d)\n", signal);
                        ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, pid, NULL, signal);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {
        printf("[Child] Raising SIGSTOP\n");

        // Allow parent to PTRACE_SEIZE
        if (raise(SIGSTOP) != 0) {
            _exit(255);
        }

        printf("[Child] Resumed from SIGSTOP\n");
        _exit(0);
    }

    // Wait for stop
    int status;
    waitpid(pid, &status, WSTOPPED);

    ptrace(PTRACE_SEIZE, pid, NULL, PTRACE_O_TRACESYSGOOD);

    // Allow child to continue
    kill(pid, SIGCONT);

    handle_events(pid);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

---

`strace` seems to call `PTRACE_SYSCALL` whenever it sees a non-group-stop `PTRACE_EVENT_STOP`:

- https://github.com/strace/strace/blob/b1e1eb7731e50900bb4591a3a71b96ab37e106a8/strace.c#L2360
- https://github.com/strace/strace/blob/b1e1eb7731e50900bb4591a3a71b96ab37e106a8/strace.c#L2408-L2409

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to figure out why the event occurs.

When a process is being ptrace'd with `PTRACE_SEIZE`, `ptrace_trap_notify()` will be called to [set `JOBCTL_TRAP_NOTIFY`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.12/source/kernel/signal.c#L792) when [`SIGCONT` is received](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.12/source/kernel/signal.c#L839) or `JOBCTL_TRAP_STOP` will be set when a [stopping signal is received](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.12/source/kernel/signal.c#L2072). `get_signal()` will check for `JOBCTL_TRAP_MASK` (ie. `JOBCTL_TRAP_STOP | JOBCTL_TRAP_NOTIFY`) and [call `do_jobctl_trap()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.12/source/kernel/signal.c#L2222). [`do_jobctl_trap()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.12/source/kernel/signal.c#L2092) will then either send `<stopping signal> | (PTRACE_EVENT_STOP << 8)` if the process enters group stop or else it will send `SIGTRAP | (PTRACE_EVENT_STOP << 8)`.

Thus, when using `PTRACE_SEIZE`:

- A stopping signal will result in a `<stopping signal> | (PTRACE_EVENT_STOP << 8)` event
- A `SIGCONT` signal will result in a `SIGTRAP | (PTRACE_EVENT_STOP << 8)` event

This behavior appears to have been introduced in [commit `fb1d910c178ba0c5bc32d3e5a9e82e05b7aad3cd`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=fb1d910c178ba0c5bc32d3e5a9e82e05b7aad3cd).